# I have to typecast but their example does not (Jsoup Document type)

Tags: java, jsoup

Simple question, this is the example from the [Jsoup introduction page](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/introduction/parsing-a-document):

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
  + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
```

Now that does not work for me, Netbeans says that you can't just go from the node document to document type. Fair enough, so I typecast and the error goes away. Like so:

EDIT: This doesn't work!

```
String html = "<html><head><title>First parse</title></head>"
  + "<body><p>Parsed HTML into a doc.</p></body></html>";
Document doc = (Document) Jsoup.parse(html);
```

TYPECAST does not work:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: org.jsoup.nodes.Document cannot be cast to org.w3c.dom.Document
    at scraping.Scraping.main(Scraping.java:24)
```

(Its kinda frustrating when learning something new and then you just get all these errors from examples that are formatted exactly as the documentation shows)

EDIT: This is the error:

```
required: org.w3c.dom.Document
found:    ord.jsoup.nodes.Document
```

Many thanks

Comment: All the `parse()` methods return a `Document`. Which version of jsoup is this ? Jsoup can parse whatever you push to it. If ajax changes the HTML after passing it over to JSOUP, it will obviously not parse the new content.

Comment: I am using Jsoup 1.7.2, Thanks about the Ajax comment, I know I need to re-parse every time the data comes through. Just some of the frameworks I have used before had problems with AJAX.

Comment: You're using `Document` classes from two different packages. Your declaration declares one (`org.w3c.dom.Document`), and `parse` returns the other. I'm less than convinced a type cast actually fixes it.

Comment: Oh right, I am trying to write a function that reads and prints to the screen from `doc`, are you saying this won't work? Whats the correct Document type to use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In case any one is interested, the document type is apart of the Jsoup Library, access via import:

```
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
```

That makes the code work fine (See the example on the Jsoup webpage)